# how the gpsd client recognize server without using internet connection?

Tags: 14.04, networking, ntp

I have 2 laptop with a IP address, for example:

```
**Receiver:    192.168.21.168**
**Transmitter: 192.168.11.186**
```

usually,on the Receiver computer, I use the comment **sudo ntpdate -d 192.168.21.168** with internet connection for both computers, I have this message:

```
23 Mar 21:49:05 ntpdate[10078]: ntpdate 4.2.8p4@1.3265-o Wed Oct  5 12:34:47 UTC 2016 (1)
Looking for host 192.168.1.231 and service ntp
192.168.1.231 reversed to Lab-X230.fios-router.home
host found : Lab-X230.fios-router.home
transmit(192.168.1.231)
receive(192.168.1.231)
transmit(192.168.1.231)
receive(192.168.1.231)
transmit(192.168.1.231)
receive(192.168.1.231)
transmit(192.168.1.231)
receive(192.168.1.231)
server 192.168.1.231, port 123
stratum 3, precision -23, leap 00, trust 000
refid [192.168.1.231], delay 0.02567, dispersion 0.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    dc7ef94a.6dba5ca9  Thu, Mar 23 2017 21:47:54.428
originate timestamp: dc7ef997.3f55cd9c  Thu, Mar 23 2017 21:49:11.247
transmit timestamp:  dc7ef997.3f4c834d  Thu, Mar 23 2017 21:49:11.247
filter delay:  0.02574  0.02567  0.02574  0.02571 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: -0.00000 -0.00000 -0.00002 -0.00000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.02567, dispersion 0.00000
offset -0.000003

23 Mar 21:49:11 ntpdate[10078]: adjust time server 192.168.1.231 offset -0.000003 sec
```

suddenly, internet disconnect, I tried to use again same comment, and it show me this message:

```
 7 Apr 14:16:26 ntpdate[24022]: ntpdate 4.2.8p4@1.3265-o Wed Oct  5 12:34:47 UTC 2016 (1)
Looking for host 192.168.21.168 and service ntp
host found : 192.168.21.168
transmit(192.168.21.168)
transmit(192.168.21.168)
transmit(192.168.21.168)
transmit(192.168.21.168)
transmit(192.168.21.168)
192.168.21.168: Server dropped: no data
server 192.168.21.168, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [192.168.21.168], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  1:28:16.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  1:28:16.000
transmit timestamp:  dc925600.fef4c72c  Fri, Apr  7 2017 14:16:32.995
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

 7 Apr 14:16:34 ntpdate[24022]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

My question is: how to get **"djust time server 192.168.1.231 offset -0.000003 sec"** messeage without having internet connection?

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello again. I think that you mean ntp client, instead of gpsd client. Also, I see 192.168.1.*, 192.168.21.*, and 192.168.11.* addresses. Are these really on one subnet, or three subnets? Also, when you say transmitter/receiver do you mean server/client? Was your first ntpdate command done on a different machines in the first vs second example? And when you say Internet disconnect, where does the break occur? At the DSL/cable modem? At the NTP server?

Comment: @heynnema: Yes, I mean ntp client. I mean transmitter/receiver are server/client, and I supposed to type **sudo ntpdate -d 192.168.11.186** maybe the typing skill.

Comment: @heynnema: I would assume the comment which I used, is client. If **ntpdate** command is done by using its own or another  computer's IP address,  I will have first example, with internet connection. If no internet connection (disconnect wifi or cable), I will have second example.

Comment: @heynnema: and I do not clear your question: **"where does the break occur? At the DSL/cable modem? At the NTP server?"**, maybe at the NTP server.

Comment: I guess that I'm confused about how all of this is glued together, and if the Internet goes down, does it go down for all 3 machines, just the client or server? Exactly where does the Internet disconnect? ps: you may wish to edit the question, change the gpsd/transmitter/receiver things we discussed, and see if there's any way to clarify your problem description :-)

Comment: @heynnema :  either way, I mean: it can be all 2 machines, it can be only 1 client or server disconnect, I will have this problem.

Comment: I guess that I have no more ideas about your problem this time. Sorry.